# Can forest plots present subgroups also ordered by year (Metafor, R)?

Tags: r

Is there any way to have subgroups sorted by two variables on a `forest` plot? I am not concerned with analysis (e.g. mixed effects), only with the presentation of data from subgroups preserving year order of studies.

When creating a forest plot separated into subgroups, each subgroup loses its year order. 
This can be seen in the example forest plot for the dat.bcg [data](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/plots%3aforest_plot_with_subgroups). Relevant part of forest command: `order=order(dat.bcg$alloc)`

No matter how I organise the source data in advance, I lose the year order once I order by subgroup. I have tried ordering the data exactly as required and using the rows command to separate it in the forest plot (rather than order command). This still re-orders the studies (they usually end up in reverse year order, as in the linked example). The order command does not seem to allow two simultaneous variables to be applied. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
 order=order(dat.bcg$alloc,dat.bcg$year)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I had tried that, and year order comes out with most recent first (which is OK). I would like to get year order running consecutively from earliest to latest. Including "decreasing = TRUE/FALSE" does not help - that condition is then applied to both arguments in the order command.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to first reorder the original dataset in the desired order. For example, in the example linked, first use:

```
dat.bcg <- dat.bcg[order(dat.bcg$alloc, 5000-dat.bcg$year),]
```

With `5000-dat.bcg$year`, we get ordering in decreasing order for `year` (there may be a more elegant way of doing that). This should be done even before the call to `rma()`. Now one can run through the example, but leaving out the the `order=order(dat.bcg$alloc)` part in the call to `forest()` (that is already taken care of with the reordering above).